# No functions get exported into DLL despite proper dllExport - Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a base class (`QIndicator`) and I want to implement derived classes in DLLs. The DLL project in Visual Studio 2012 for a sample derived class has the following code:

**header file with base class**

```
#ifndef _DLL_COMMON_INDICATOR_
#define _DLL_COMMON_INDICATOR_

// define the DLL storage specifier macro
#if defined DLL_EXPORT
    #define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DECLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class QIndicator 
{
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
};

extern "C"      
{
    // declare the factory function for exporting a pointer to QIndicator
    DECLDIR QIndicator * __stdcall getIndicatorPtr(void);
}

#endif
```

**source file with derived class**

```
#define DLL_EXPORT

#include "indicator.h"

class QIndicatorDer : public QIndicator
{
    public:
        QIndicatorDer       (void) : QIndicator(){};
        ~QIndicatorDer      (void){};

    private:
        // list of QIndicatorDer parameters
        int x2;
        int y2;
};

extern "C"     
{
    DECLDIR QIndicator * __stdcall getIndicatorPtr(void)
    {
        return new QIndicatorDer();
    };
}
```

The problem I have is that upon successful build, the produced DLL file does not contain the exported `getIndicatorPtr` function (as shown by DependencyWalker). I checked whether the `dllexport` keyword gets propagated properly into the declaration of `getIndicatorPtr` and it does.

Another interesting problem is that I already have another derived class like this, in another DLL project, that I created some months ago. This older project is basically the same and everything works well there. I checked all properties of both the old and the current projects, and they seem identical. So I ran out of ideas, why I can't get `getIndicatorPtr` to export.

Any help is much appreciated, 
Daniel

Comment: Why do you use ``__stdcall`` here?

Comment: ``QIndicator`` class is not exported. You need to export the class, too.

Comment: Found it in a tutorial, honestly (trying all possibilities know to internet to explain this DLL behaviour) ..works the same without it.

Comment: @user2225104 Wrong. As long as `QIndicator` doesn't contain any code, he doesn't need to export it. It contains only data members, so including this class` header is enough to properly use it.

Comment: I have many other base-derived classes with the logics implemented. Nowhere is the base class exported, the DLL logics is the same and all works.

Comment: @DanielBencik This may not work in all cases. Sometimes it is required to export also a base class. In these cases Visual C++ will give you a warning 4275: `non dll-interface class 'A' used as base for dll-interface class 'B'`.

Comment: Right - I assumed too much when saying that. I assumed he will add stuff to the class later on or that this is a cooked down version of what he actually has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's not being exported. Why?

`__declspec` specifier should only be placed in the **declaration** of a function, not it's definition. Also, avoid something like `#define DLL_EXPORT`. Preprocessor definitions should either defined in project properties (MSVC) or command line option (`-D` in GCC, for example).

Look at you code:

**Header**

```
extern "C"      
{
    DECLDIR QIndicator * __stdcall getIndicatorPtr(void);
}
```

When compiler parses this header, is sees `DECLDIR` as `dllimport` (because you define `DLL_EXPORT` in `.cpp`). Then in `.cpp`, it suddenly appears as `dllexport`. Which one is used? The first one.

So, leave your header (it's fine), but change your source:

```
//#define DLL_EXPORT -> remove this!

#include "indicator.h"

class QIndicatorDer : public QIndicator
{
    //...
};

extern "C"     
{
    /* DECLDIR -> and this! */ QIndicator * __stdcall getIndicatorPtr(void)
    {
        return new QIndicatorDer();
    };
}
```

Then, go to project properties (I assume you use Visual Studio) and then `C/C++` -> `Preprocessor` -> `Preprocessor Definitions` and add there `DLL_EXPORT=1`.

That should work.

Comment: Mateusz, thank you! The code works after your changed. Regards to Poland!

Comment: `__declspec` in the definition was fine and correct.  Moving the macro definition to the project properties was the important step here.