# dllexport functions not exported

Tags: c++, dllimport, dllexport

I have done everything according to MSDN documentation and still my functions do not get exported.
[LINK1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-into-an-application-using-declspec-dllimport?view=vs-2019) [LINK2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=vs-2019) [LINK3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120525-00/?p=7533)

Here is what I have (2 projects, DLL and App importing from the dll) which looks like this (short version):

**DLL functions.h**

```
#prgma once
#ifdef COMPILE_DLL
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // COMPILE_DLL

namespace wsl
{
        EXPORT bool PointInTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x, int y);
}
```

**DLL functions.cpp**

```
#include "functions.h"

namespace wsl
{
    bool PointInTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x, int y)
    {
         // implementation...
         return true;
    }
}
```

**DLL dllmain.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(
    [[maybe_unused]] HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    [[maybe_unused]] LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**NOTE:** there are several other headers and cpp files in dll project, all being compiled, but no function is exported.

**Application main.cpp**

```
#include "functions.h"

int main()
{
    wsl::PointInTriangle(0, 0, 20, 0, 10, 30, 10, 15);
    return 0;
}
```

**Program output:**

> 2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl
>   wsl::PointInCircleSector(int,int,int,float,float)"
>   (__imp_?PointInCircleSector@wsl@@YA_NHHHMM@Z) referenced in function
>   main 2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl
>   wsl::PointInTriangle(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)"
>   (__imp_?PointInTriangle@wsl@@YA_NHHHHHHHH@Z) referenced in function
>   main 2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl
>   wsl::PointInEllipse(int,int,int,int,int,int)"
>   (__imp_?PointInEllipse@wsl@@YA_NHHHHHH@Z) referenced in function main
>   2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl
>   wsl::PointInCircle(int,int,int,int,int)"
>   (__imp_?PointInCircle@wsl@@YA_NHHHHH@Z) referenced in function main
>   2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl
>   wsl::PointInRectangle(int,int,int,int,int,int)"
>   (__imp_?PointInRectangle@wsl@@YA_NHHHHHH@Z) referenced in function
>   main 2>C:\Users\User\source\repos\WindowsSuperLibrary\x64\Debug
>   DLL\MathSample.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
>   2>Done building project "MathSample.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Can you please explain what is the problem here?

I've run dumpbin /EXPORTS against the dll and can confirm no functions are exported.

`COMPILE_DLL` macro is of course defined in dll project.

I did include import library into my project.

namespace name is the same in both header and cpp file.

Comment: Other than linking, try dependencywalker to find out what gets exported, because it may not be the cause of your linking problems. Another thing to check is the difference between a version that works and one that doesn't. For a working one, I'd suggest VS's auto-generated DLL project skeleton. If that still doesn't give you any insights, extract a [mcve] for posting here. BTW: For problems with code that is required among other reasons because it avoids useless discussions about a possibly relevant spelling mistake in the code you posted.

Comment: I already tried using default project template, and also checked the exports with dumpbin, nothing get exported. However if I do put `EXPORT` into function definitions in cpp files in addition to header files the yes, it will get exported but it should work by just puting the macro in a declaration. (edit: and I think this is minimum reproducible example)

Comment: As @AlexF says, you need the `EXPORT` attribute in your DLL source (.cpp) files, not just in the header.

Comment: ok, I omitted namespace, I'll update my post., I did import the library into client application of course

Comment: @Adrian that definitelly works, but there are plenty of online and stackoverflow answers telling that EXPORT in cpp files is not needed, not even documentation says that. only in declaration is needed

Comment: Interesting, I just checked, what project template is that?, my DLL project template in VS2019 doesn't have any code except DllMain and precompiled header.

Comment: See answer. But can you link to an example on Stack Overflow that denies this? Maybe a chance to cast my first downvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for a function declared in a source file for a DLL to actually be exported, you must do one of two things:

Either (1) add the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute to the function ***in the source where it is defined*** (not just in a header).

Or (2) Add the function to the list of `EXPORTS` in a Module Definition File (.def).

Available documentation (especially older stuff) tends to assume the use of the .def file `EXPORTS` method, and can be quite misleading.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your answer and declare msdn documentation bad, I'l post a link to stack overflow that confirms EXPORT in cpp is not needed soon.

Comment: @metablaster MSDN documentation is generally very good, IMO. It's just that you need to read it wearing Microsoft-Compatible spectacles! (Comes with time.)

Comment: ok, no problem I love MSDN, but see also here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471901/no-functions-get-exported-into-dll-despite-proper-dllexport-visual-studio

Comment: @metablaster The issue there is more complex: (non-)exported classes and contradicting definitions of the 'EXPORT' macro.

Comment: This answer is not correct, MSVC++ is happy with the __declspec on the declaration and doesn't require it to be repeated on the definition.

Comment: @HansPassant So how come the suggestion fixed the OP's problem?

Comment: This is easy to verify for yourself.  Unless you guessed at it.  We'd be all ahead if the OP posted the solution he found himself, hopefully he remembers.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree with you because that's what documentatino says but it doesn't work, why not? what's wrong with my posted code?